# Heroku app idles even though I am using new relic to ping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, heroku, newrelic

in order to prevent heroku to idle my app I use newrelic.
This resulted in having a vast number of sessions in my rails 3.2 app. Thats why I changed the ping url to an image on my landing page.
But since a few days heroku idles the app even though new relic is pinging.
So I was wondering how can I prevent heroku from idling without having my homepage as ping url in order to prevent this vast number of sessions?

I look forward to hearing your thoughts...
Phil

Comment: in all fairness, I'm surprised that Heroku don't just prevent NewRelic availability pings from keeping apps alive if customers aren't paying for their services.

Comment: I am more than willing to pay, as soon as I have usage. But that's the point, I dont have users yet and thats why heroku idles..

Answer (score 1):

You have a few ways to achieve that:

1. Pay. Buy an extra web dyno and your app will never idle out.
2. Use [Uptime Robot](http://uptimerobot.com/) (not sure about the sessions issue here)

Comment: My application idles because I dont have the critical mass of users yet. So I dont want to pay. Using uptime robot will lead to the same problem with the sessions...

Comment: From what I know and read, you do not have any other options. I mean, you have many tools to ping your site, but all of those will create the many sessions problem.